# Evento WM_KEYDOWN não sendo chamado

Tags: c++

Estou desenvolvendo um programa simples em C++ apenas para testes com uma interface gráfica mas ele não está chamando o evento WM_KEYDOWN, o programa é baseado em diálogo. A interface gráfica foi criada através do ResEdit. Alguém poderia me dizer o porquê disso? Abaixo o código principal dele:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include "resource.

BOOL CALLBACK DlgMain(HWND hwndDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(uMsg)
    {
        case WM_INITDIALOG:
        {
            return TRUE;
        }

        case WM_KEYDOWN: // problema aqui
        {
            if(LOWORD(wParam) == VK_ESCAPE)
            {
                PostMessage(hwndDlg, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
            }
            return TRUE;
        }

        case WM_CLOSE:
        {
            if(MessageBox(hwndDlg, "Você deseja realmente sair?", "Confirmação", MB_OKCANCEL | MB_ICONQUESTION) == IDOK) {
                EndDialog(hwndDlg, 0);
            }

            return TRUE;
        }

        case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            switch(LOWORD(wParam))
            {
                case ID_LEAVE:
                {
                    SendMessage(hwndDlg, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
                    return TRUE;
                }
            }
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}


int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    InitCommonControls();
    return DialogBox(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(DLG_MAIN), NULL, (DLGPROC)DlgMain);
}
```

Comment: Acabei de depurar o programa, tudo funciona normal mas o evento WM_KEYDOWN nunca sequer é chamado para nenhuma tecla, seria alguma incompatibilidade do código gerado pelo ResEdit? Pois quando crio tudo a mão (a interface, botões, registro da classe, etc) não tenho esse problema.

Comment: Qual erro que dá ?

Comment: A aspas ausente em `#include "resource.` foi só um erro de digitação?

Comment: Sim, Jefferson. Eu tinha alterado algumas poucas coisas enquanto estava colocando aqui o código, foi apenas um erro de digitação. Matheus, não é dado nenhum erro, o programa compila e executa normalmente, apenas não acontece nada quando pressiono a tecla ESC nem qualquer outra. O evento WM_KEYDOWN não está sendo chamado, pois em testes aqui coloquei para que quando este seja chamado, mostrar uma mensagem na tela, não importando a tecla que foi pressionada e mesmo assim não funciona.